# Firefox bug loading a function when content appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function (bookblock) in a html page. If I open the page with Firefox, it works flawlessy. However, I have another page that loads the first in a div, after a click. It's loaded as an object.

```
document.getElementById(container).innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="page.html" ></object>';
```

In this case, Firefox breaks up all:

```
TypeError: $(...).bookblock is not a function
```

This is the function

```
                    config.$bookBlock.bookblock({
                        speed : 800,
                        shadowSides : 0.8,
                        shadowFlip : 0.7,
                        onEndFlip: function( page, isLimit ) { 
                       //other things here 
                                };
                    });
```

Note that the page itself works without errors.

Chrome opens both pages without any problem.

Comment: I'd actually consider Chrome to be the browser that's got a bug.

Comment: I have no idea how to further investigate the bug